# How to replace only specific groups in a match in R using stringr package?

Tags: r, regex, replace, stringr

In my R project I am using package [stringr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0) to perform regex operations.

```r
text <- "My code #snippet wanna get this# is simple"
pattern <- "#([^ \t]+) (.+)#"
```

`pattern` looks for stuff inside `#...#`. The following code:

```r
stringr::str_match_all(text, pattern)
```

Will give me the content of the groups I am targeting:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]                       [,2]      [,3]            
[1,] "#snippet wanna get this#" "snippet" "wanna get this"
```

---

How do I replace the content of **group 3** (and only that) with a different text? The final desired result would be:

```
My code #snippet REPLACED WITH THIS# is simple
```

I am playing with `stringr::str_replace_all` but I don't seem to get how to solve this issue. I keep replacing the whole match and not just a single group content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may capture what you need to keep and just match what you need to replace, use

```
> gsub("(#[^ \t#]+ )[^#]*(#)", "\\1REPLACED WITH THIS\\2", text)
[1] "My code #snippet REPLACED WITH THIS# is simple"
```

**Details**

- `(#[^ \t#]+ )` - Group 1: `#`, then any 1+ chars other than `#`, space and tab, and a space
- `[^#]*` - 0+ chars other than `#`
- `(#)` - Group 2: a `#` char

Another way: use `gsubfn` with a pattern where all your pattern parts are captured into separate groups and then rebuild the replacement after performing the required manipulations:

```
> gsubfn::gsubfn("(#[^ \t#]+ )([^#]*)(#)", function(x, y, z) paste0(x, "REPLACED WITH THIS", z), text)
[1] "My code #snippet REPLACED WITH THIS# is simple"
```

Here, the `x`, `y` and `z` refer to the groups defined in the pattern:

```
(#[^ \t#]+ )([^#]*)(#)
| --- x ---||- y -||z|
```

With `stringr`, you may - *but you should be very careful with this* - use a pattern with lookbehind/lookahead:

```
> stringr::str_replace_all(text, "(?<=#[^ \t#]{1,1000} )[^#]*(?=#)", "REPLACED WITH THIS")
[1] "My code #snippet REPLACED WITH THIS# is simple"
```

The `(?<=#[^ \t#]{1,1000} )` lookbehind works because it matches a *known* length pattern (the `{1,1000}` says there can be from 1 to 1000 occurrences of any chars but space, tab and `#`), and this "[constrained-width lookbehind](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html#width)" is supported since `stringr` uses [ICU regex library](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no way of achieving this with `stringr`?

Comment: @Andry I would not suggest you should use `stringr` here. I would use other, safer methods.